# Is my keepass great? How can I improve it?

Tags: password-management, keepass

Here is my keepass setup:

**Cloud**

- Gmail 1 Google Drive: holds database
- Gmail 2 Google Drive: holds key file

**Hard Drive**

- Computer: holds database (leave at home)
- USB 1: holds database  (always have with me)
- USB 2: holds key file (leave at home)
- USB 3: holds key file (always have with me)
- USB 4: holds Gmail 1 id, Gmail 2 id, and master password (leave at home)
- USB 5: holds Gmail 1 id, Gmail 2 id, and master password (always have with me)

**Paper**

- Paper1: Gmail 1 id, Gmail 2 id, and master password (leave at home)
- Paper2: Gmail 1 id, Gmail 2 id, and master password (always have with me)

Comment: Is it worse for you to lose access to your database? Or for someone else to have access to your database?

Comment: What do you want to protect yourself from?

Answer (score 1):

Having the DB file and Key file in the same place pretty much defeats the purpose of the Key File (especially if its stored Online). If someone has access to your Google Drive Account they "only" need your Password.

I would also consider trying to only remember your Master-Password (Diceware can help) and not having it in so many personal places.

Also keep in mind what your Threat model is.